# Output value that is possibly undefined

Tags: typescript

I have a variable named `root` that may or may not be undefined. I will only know that at run time.

```
const root = resolvedRoot || await this.fileSystem.getCurrentUserHome();
console.log('root.uri = ' + root.uri);
```

The parameter `root.uri` may or may not exist due to the above either/or syntax.

Is there a way to safely and cleanly output `root.uri`?

Comment: What do you mean 'safely'? Making sure that `root` is defined?

Comment: I suppose you want to avoid runtime errors? `if (root && root.uri) { ... }`

Comment: @OscarPaz Well, if root does not exist, then nothing after the dot exists neither. In this case `.uri`. So instead of just trying to acces `uri` and hoping it might go well, rather find a way to handle this more clean.

Comment: "due to the above either/or syntax" --- if either operand returns an object with `uri` property - then how is it possible?

Comment: @bugs Thanks, that looks like a possible solution. Is that the way to go in TypeScript or are there other ways to to hande your described behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check for whether `root` is `undefined` or not:

```
const root = resolvedRoot || await this.fileSystem.getCurrentUserHome();
if (root && root.uri) {
    console.log('root.uri = ' + root.uri);
}
```

This way, you check that `root` exists and is defined, and, if it is, then that it has a `uri` property which is neither `undefined` or `null`.

If `root` is `undefined` or `null`, the sceond part of the condition es not evaluated, so no problem there.